# Formatting a numeric column as percent in flextable package in R

Tags: r, flextable, officer

For example I am using iris data:

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% 
  colformat_num(j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                             "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), digits = 1)
```

What would be the proper syntax if I wish to have "Petal.Width" values in percent format? I could not find colformat_percent function. Is there a way to make up for it using flextable syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is an official function [fmt_pct](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/fmt_pct.html).

```
ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% mk_par(
  j = "Sepal.Length",
  value = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Sepal.Length, formatter = fmt_pct)))
```

Alternatively, you can format the cells into characters before converting it to a flextable:

```
percent <- function(x, digits = 2, format = "f", ...) {    
  paste0(formatC(x * 100, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%")
}

ft_test <- head(iris) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~percent(.x))) %>%
  flextable()
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `set_formatter` as documented in the manual, using the iris data (!)

```r
ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% 
  set_formatter( Petal.Width = function(x) sprintf( "%.1f%%", x*100 ) )
```

Here is the examples section from the [manual](https://rdrr.io/cran/flextable/man/set_formatter.html#heading-6):

```r
Examples:

     ft <- flextable( head( iris ) )
     ft <- set_formatter( x = ft,
             Sepal.Length = function(x) sprintf("%.02f", x),
             Sepal.Width = function(x) sprintf("%.04f", x)
           )
     ft <- theme_vanilla( ft )
     ft
```